# Regarding Tree Control in c#

Tags: c#, view, tree, treeview

This is my code for retrieving data from database and displaying it in Tree control

```
String empid = ValueBox1.Text;
string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeDatabase"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReportingManagers", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpID",SqlDbType.Int,0).Value =  empid;

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
                //Here "Node" Means It Will Add Nodes As All Root Nodes...
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
 }
 dr.Close();
```

I am getting error in this line:

```
 TreeView1.Nodes.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

> Error :The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode)' has some invalid arguments.
>
> Error : Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode'

Please help me to solve this issue..

Answer (score 2):

The error message you got is pretty self explanatory. In the below line, it expects a TreeNode object to be added to the collection.

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

Try this:

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(dr.GetValue(0).ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance of the TreeNode class instead of trying to add the String value directly.

See this link for an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodes.aspx